# xpath expression to read value based on value of sibling

Tags: xpath

I've below xml and would like to read the value of 'Value' tag whose Name matches 'test2'. I'm using the below xpath , but did not work. Can someone help.

`/*[ local-name()='OutputData']/*[ local-name()='OutputDataItem']/*[ local-name()='Name'][normalize-space(.) = 'test2']//*[local-name()='Value']/text()`

```
             <get:OutputData>
              <get:OutputDataItem>
                 <get:Name>test1</get:Name>
                 <get:Value/>
              </get:OutputDataItem>
              <get:OutputDataItem>
                 <get:Name>test2</get:Name>
                 <get:Value>B5B4</get:Value>
              </get:OutputDataItem>
              <get:OutputDataItem>
                 <get:Name>test3</get:Name>
                 <get:Value/>
              </get:OutputDataItem>
              <get:OutputDataItem>
                 <get:Name>OP_VCscEncrptCd_VAR</get:Name>
                 <get:Value/>
              </get:OutputDataItem>                  
           </get:OutputData>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This should work I think:

```
//*[local-name()="get:Name" and text()="test2"]/following-sibling::*[local-name()="get:Value"]/text()
```

Answer (score 2):

You were close, but because the `get:name` and `get:value` are siblings, you need to adjust your XPath a little.

Your XPath was attempting to address `get:value` elements that were descendants of `get:name`, rather than as siblings. Move the criteria that is filtering the `get:name` into a predicate, then step down into the `get:value`:

```
/*[ local-name()='OutputData']/*[ local-name()='OutputDataItem']
  [*[ local-name()='Name'][normalize-space(.) = 'test2']]/*[local-name()='Value']/text()
```

You could also combine the criteria of the predicate filter on the `get:name` and use an `and`:

```
/*[ local-name()='OutputData']/*[ local-name()='OutputDataItem']
  [*[ local-name()='Name' and normalize-space(.) = 'test2']]/*[local-name()='Value']/text()
```